# Is there a way I can use Tahoma font from Microsoft in latex?

Tags: fonts

Googling the question yields many posts but no definite answer. Is there a way to use Tahoma font in latex?

Comment: With XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX and package `fontspec` you can use Opentype fonts installed on your systen.

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but Alan Munn's answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25249/how-do-i-use-a-particular-font-for-a-small-section-of-text-in-my-document/37251#37251 is useful with regard to `fontspec`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have the `Tahoma.ttf` file installed in a place your system can find it (on my mac it's in `/Macintosh HD/Library/Fonts`), then using it is as simple as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tahoma}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

You have to take care to compile this with XeLaTeX (`xelatex`) or LuaLaTeX (`lualatex`) instead of regular LaTeX.